# SQL group by before joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, left-join

I have a table where I would like to get a value added from another transaction table, so the ralationship is currently many to many. Therefore I would like to group by the transaction table before joining the two tables in a left join with the Table 1 as master. I have been searching for a solution, but havnt found one.

Table 1:

```
SELECT 
       [Job No_]
      ,[Document Type]
      ,[No_]
      ,[Document No_]
      ,[Version]
      ,[Shipment Date]
  FROM [XX].[dbo].[XX]
```

Table 2:

```
SELECT 
       [Document No_]
      ,SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount]
  FROM [XX].[dbo].[YY]

  GROUP BY [Document No_]
```

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fW3O.png)

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Hi i have attached an example in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the given details (and if I got the question correctly), you can join the table using the following without any issue:

```
SELECT 
       [Job No_]
      ,[Document Type]
      ,[No_]
      ,[Document No_]
      ,[Version]
      ,[Shipment Date]
      ,X.Amount
  FROM [XX].[dbo].[XX] MST
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Document No_], SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount] 
             FROM [XX].[dbo].[YY] GROUP BY [Document No_])X 
                --ON X.[Document No_] = MST.[Document No_] --commented as per the image
                ON X.[Document No_] = MST.[No_]
```

Comment: I have tried this one and the join works, but all data in X.Amount is NULL

Comment: @Mr.Andersen based on the image you posted, column No_ from Table_1 is matching with column [Document No_] of Table_2. Please change the join condition. I have also added the new condition to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One convenient -- and performance -- approach is to use a correlated subquery or `cross apply`:

```
select xx.*,
       (select coalesce(sum(amount), 0)
        from [XX].[dbo].[YY] yy
        where yy.[Document No_] = xx.[Document No_]
       ) as amount
from [XX].[dbo].[XX] xx;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `yy([Document No_], amount)`.  Also, if you add a `where` clause to the outer query, this can be much more efficient than pre-aggregating.

Comment: Hi Gordon - the result of [Amount] is all NULLS when i try it?

Comment: Hi again Gordon - thanks for the help, it works now as I change the join as Sacse mention

Comment: @Mr.Andersen . . . `COALESCE()` fixes that problem.